# How to ensure that the while loop isn't stuck on one input for an airline reservation system?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner at Python so bear with me!

I'm trying to type code that makes an airline reservation system. I'm making a very simple version first before adding more code.

My issue is that with the code below:

```
class airline_reservations():

    def __init__(self,type_of_seat,no_of_seats):

        self.type_of_seat = type_of_seat
        self.no_of_seats = no_of_seats

    def check_availability(no_of_seats):
        first = 14
        business = 76
        economy = 399
        total_seats = first + business + economy
        remaining_seats = total_seats - no_of_seats
        while True:
            if no_of_seats <= remaining_seats:
                seat_answer = input("Seats are available. Would you like to confirm? ")
                if seat_answer == 'yes' or 'Yes':
                    print("You have chosen your seats. Thank you.")
                elif seat_answer == 'no':
                    seat_answer2 = input("Would you like to start over? ")
                else:
                    input("We cannot recognize this input, please try again.")
                break
```

Under the loop, regardless of what input (yes, no etc), I always get 'you have chosen your seats, thank you.' I can't seem to get the other two regardless.

What should I do?

Comment: `seat_answer == 'yes' or 'YES'` will be parsed as `(seat_answer == 'yes') or ('YES')` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: take away the complex logic of checking for various cases of letters just call `.lower()` on the string and the explicitly check `seat_answer = input("Seats are available. Would you like to confirm? ").lower()` then just do `if seat_answer == "yes":`

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help! It works now! :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
if seat_answer == 'yes' or 'Yes':
```

is NOT equivalent to this:

```
if (seat_answer == 'yes') or (seat_answer == 'Yes'):
```

Instead, it is equivalent to:

```
if (seat_answer == 'yes') or ('Yes')
```

which will always evaluate to `True` because `'Yes'` (or any non-empty string) evaluates to `True` in a conditional.

Even if it were to be parenthesized as:

```
if seat_answer == ('yes' or 'Yes')
```

it would still NOT be the same as `if (seat_answer == 'yes') or (seat_answer == 'Yes')`, but just `if (seat_answer == 'yes')`, since `('yes' or 'Yes')` evaluates to `'yes'`.

---

To fix this, use:

```
if seat_answer in ('yes', 'Yes'):
```

or:

```
if seat_answer.lower() == 'yes':
```